# Is there a number which gives different value after I multiply it with another number and then divide it with the same number?

Tags: calculus

Basically, let's say I've got integer `A` and decimal number `B`. After I multiply those two and get another number `C`, I would like to know if there is any number `B` which wouldn't give again integer `A` after dividing `C` and `B`?
So:

```
A * B = C , BUT C / B not equals A
```

Comment: For $B\neq 0$ the equation $AB=C$ implies that $A=C/B$, because $AB/B=A$.

Comment: In the reals, this will always be the case. (except for $B=0$)

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand why this is tagged [tag:calculus]... can you explain that, please?  I think that [tag:algebra-precalculus] and/or [tag:arithmetic] might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *definition* of $C/B=A$ is that $B=AC,$ so if you're asking a math question, the answer is no, unless $B=0$ so that $C/B$ is undefined.  If you're asking about floating-point arithmetic on a computer, the answer may be different. I'm not sure about that, but a question about computer arithmetic would better be asked on Computer Science Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

I Think it's not depend on B! this will happen because of round off error.
if you write the numbers in fraction always the the numerator and denominator will cancel each other.
it's simple:
$$AB=C$$ multiply both side with$ \frac1B$
$$A=\frac{C}{B}$$
and again multiply both side with B

$$AB=C$$
but when we use decimal number usually we have round off error. for example. 
$$\frac{A}{3}=~0.333A$$
and if we multiply both side with 3:
$$A=0.999A$$.
in numerical calculation you should be cautious about this!
in rutin problems it's not important because the computer will compute to many digit (like 0.000000000000000000000000000001) but in the problems like CFD problem sometimes it's very important and may cause bad results!